# "Facebook Store" Extension for magento is not connecting to localserver?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have installed a magento extension to connect my magento store to facebook store. I want to test the functionality in localhost before I set it in live server. This is the extension I have installed in local.

**http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/fbshops**

This is the error I am facing with the facebook extension.

**Error! You are using local host, or your IP is not accessible from outside, please contact your hosting provider.**

Is there any way available to test this facebook module in localserver ?
I am using magento 1.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to make your IP accessible to the outside world, this you can do if you have a static IP. You will need to forward all the request to your IP by port forwarding it to the web server.

And you will have to use your External IP Address instead of localhost in magento to check this. You can get your external ip address from [here](http://www.whatismyip.com/).